# How to use BigQueryToPostgresOperator

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I'm new using apache-airflow on GCP and I'm trying to use the BigQueryToPostgresOperator on a DAG within Dataproc serverless to send a table from Bigquery to Cloud SQL, specifically to a database on postgresql, this from different projects on GCP, but I get the error ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "database_type".

This is the DAG code that I have

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_postgres import BigQueryToPostgresOperator

DAG_ID = "BQTOPOSTGRES"
DATASET_NAME = "test_dataset"
TABLE = "test_table"
destination_table = "destination_test_table"

with DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example", "bigquery"],
) as dag:
    bigquery_to_postgres = BigQueryToPostgresOperator(
        # [START howto_operator_bigquery_to_postgres]
        task_id="bigquery_to_postgres",
        dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE}", #the big query table of origin
        postgres_conn_id="connection_test",
        target_table_name=destination_table, # target postgres table (templated)
        replace=False,
        # [END howto_operator_bigquery_to_postgres]
    )

bigquery_to_postgres
```

I'm trying to make changes in the postgres_conn_id from airflow connections unsuccessfully, I would like to know how to make the connection and use the operator properly.

Answer (score 0):

While setting up the connection in the airflow webUI, test the configured connection. If the test is successful then you have configured the connection correctly, but based on the error it looks like the connection is not configured correctly:

1. you can check the permissions in the gcp project. Make sure your composer has access to your cloud SQL.
   [image]
2. Check the type of connection is set correctly.
   [image]
   Hope this helps